Issue with Plotting Predicted Masks
I am currently working on a deep learning project 'leaf disease segmentation'. I have trained a model over 50 epochs and obtained the following accuracy and loss metrics:
Train Loss: 19.4736, Train Accuracy: 0.9395
Validation Loss: 19.6197, Validation Accuracy: 0.9100
Test Loss: 19.6148, Test Accuracy: 0.9123
However, when I plot the predicted masks, they appear inaccurate. Is there any issue with my plotting code.
def plot_predictions(model, images, masks, num_samples=5):
    predictions = model.predict(images[:num_samples])
    for i in range(num_samples):
        plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
        plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
        plt.title('Real Image')
        plt.imshow(images[i])
        plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
        plt.title('Ground Truth Mask')
        plt.imshow(masks[i], cmap='gray')  # Assuming masks are already binary
        plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
        plt.title('Predicted Mask')
        plt.imshow(predictions[i][:, :, 0], cmap='gray')  # Convert predicted mask to binary
        plt.show()

plot_predictions(model, test_images.numpy(), test_masks_L, num_samples=5)

Original Image-Mask-Predicted Mask
Please review my code and help identify any errors that might be causing this issue?

why do you think it's the plotting and not your model/training?

Because model accuracy increased and loss decreased after each epoch. I considered this is successful training?? If this not criteria, then how can i ensure mode is working right?

maybe the evaluation of the model's predicted output vs training output has issues. you just assume that what you plotted is what the loss function evaluates. [mre] required. -- your training mask is 3-valued, your predicted mask is 2-valued. why is it not 3-valued as well? you plot it in grayscale...

thank you1 this was the problem. I was implementing 2-value predicted mask. i corrected and got the plots correctly.

Images and masks consist of 3 classes. In the above code, plotting of predicted mask was done using greyscale colormap (2-valued). Since, these masks are also 3-valued, we need colored settings. Simply replace this line of code
plt.imshow(predictions[i][:, :, 0], cmap='gray')

with this
plt.imshow(predicted_masks[i], cmap='viridis', vmin=0, vmax=2)

here is the complete code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_predictions(model, images, masks, num_samples=5):
    predictions = model.predict(images[:num_samples])
    predicted_masks = np.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)

    for i in range(num_samples):
        plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))

        # Real Image
        plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
        plt.title('Real Image')
        plt.imshow(images[i])

        # Ground Truth Mask
        plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
        plt.title('Ground Truth Mask')
        plt.imshow(masks[i], cmap='viridis', vmin=0, vmax=2)

        # Predicted Mask
        plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
        plt.title('Predicted Mask')
        plt.imshow(predicted_masks[i], cmap='viridis', vmin=0, vmax=2)

        plt.show()

plot_predictions(model, test_images.numpy(), test_masks_cat, num_samples=5)


ok, i added the context.
